# Ex Commodore 64 programmer wants to get back into programming- any suggestions?

Tags: basic, commodore

When I was a kid I wrote hundreds of programs in BASIC but then as I got older I got out of it (when I discovered girls). Now I want to get back into it again and I don't want to let my prior knowledge & experience go to waste - is there a modern language that is at least somewhat similar? Every time I try to search I get pushed toward Visual BASIC but I would rather learn a modern language that's more widely used. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also have more recent experience with HTML & CSS3

Comment: Signup for something like: codeschool.com and see what you enjoy.

Comment: Well, with recent experience in HTML and CSS3, go learn JavaScript and then Angular 2 since they fit together.

Answer (score 2):

Start from scratch.

Programming in a modern language (Object or Functional) is different enough from programming basic on a C64 that you will probably carry over more bad habits than good ones.

I would pick a language you like the look and feel of, but mostly think of what you want to do:

- ***Java*** is probably the "safe" bet, especially if you want to start a career in programming or if you want to work on Android development.
- If you want to program for Windows / Microsoft devices then ***C#***
- If you want to want to write for the Mac or iOs devices then ***Swift***.
- If you like the idea of functional programming then ***Clojure*** is a good bet.
- If you want to do web development then ***Javascript*** and maybe ***Ruby***
- If you want to work on things like machine learning or statistics then ***Python*** to start and then maybe ***R***
- If you want to be cutting edge and maybe work on some DevOps kind of things I would suggest ***Go***
- *With all of these I would suggest also learning some flavor of **SQL***

Languages I personally would generally avoid either because they are overly complex or tend to teach bad programming practices:
Objective C, C++, Perl, Lisp, Ruby

If you want to explore some other more esoteric languages I recommend two books:

- [Seven Languages in Seven Weeks](http://amzn.to/2n448jx)
- [Seven More Languages in Seven Weeks](http://amzn.to/2n4dMmp)

Keep in mind, that just because you might start from scratch it doesn't mean your prior experience goes to waste, it just may not be as useful as you may like.

Comment: Thank you for your answers guys - especially you Justin -  I really appreciate it!

Comment: @RichieMann a better form of appreciation is to vote the answer up and select it as the correct answer. Good luck and welcome back to software.

Answer (score 1):

I was in this exact position about eight years ago; whilst I could do some assembly and BASIC, these skills were (and are) generally not required in a modern context. So I went to study a Foundation Degree in Enterprise Computing in the UK (MMU affiliated) because this had Java. Due to a Government change in 2010, that cut funding to Higher Education, the 3rd year of that course was scrapped for all affiliated establishments, so I spent a year at the University of Derby on its Games Programming degree, which was all programming in C, C++, MIPs assembly, C# and Java.

I found the following useful:

- 6502 is good if you want to learn more modern assembly like MIPs; Z80 is probably good for x86/64, though that is an educated guess rather than fact (I use both 65x and Z80 in personal projects today mixed with C when I get the chance);
- C is the most beautiful language that I've ever used. I did C programming on Windows and for the PSP. I've since made Sinclair ZX81 games with C and done a bit of experimental programming for the Commodore 64 and Sinclair ZX Spectrum. I love C;
- Object Orientated programming took me a while for me to get my head around. At first, I thought an object was simply a container for computer RAM. Maybe this is a good base to think about it, maybe not;
- Going to University is a good thing because you will always learn something if you apply yourself;
- 8-bit BASIC can still teach you a thing or two if you can transpose your logic without bad practises that 8-bit BASIC encourages;
- I had most difficulty understanding databases, mostly the relational algebra side but also all other database stuff. I finally got my head around M:M relationships sometime last year after years of looking at it. If you struggle with SQL/Database stuff, don't give up;

I now work at a PHP Web Application developer with bespoke OO and Procedural frameworks. I have also worked with simpler off-the-shelf solutions such as Magento, CodeIgniter, Joomla! and ExpressionEngine (built on CodeIgniter).